# Undefined control sequence \begin{math}

Tags: equations, errors, undefined, control, sequence

I have been working to make my code working in LaTeX but I can't find any fix.
I have replaced `\textit` with `\itshape` as I have read in another topic that this could trigger the error. It's still not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} 
\item {\itshape The probability that the random variable $X$ takes values ​​in a range $I = (a,b]$ este is given by}
        \begin{equation} 
             P( a < X \leq b ) = \sum_{a<x_i \leq b} p_i, \tag{14}
        \end{equation}       
    {\itshape which is equal to the sum of the probabilities $p_i$, corresponding to the possible values $x_i$ for which \begin{math} a<x_i\leg b \end{math}.}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The error displays as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 ...s $x_i$ for which \begin{math} a<x_i\leg
                                                   b \end{math}.}
?
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is due to a user's typo and the thread is not going to be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX is notorious for unhelpful error messages.  This isn't too bad, once you know what it means: the "undefined control sequence" is at the end of the line beginning with `l.21`: `\leg`.

Comment: Which should've been `\leq` haha. Thanks!